# Publicly available Botnet Traffic dataset

Tags: botnet

Is there any publicly data set on botnet traffic for machine learning purposes. i.e traffic set for both bad and good bots

Comment: Just to clarify, are you looking for packet dumps to/from infected machines, packet dumps to/from C&C servers, or samples of the malware itself?

Comment: I am looking for packet dumps to/from infected machines but it will great to have malware samples for analysis.

Comment: Have a look at kaiten.c

Comment: Hi, just wondering if you got any better sources than the ones listed in the answers below... I am looking for P2P-based botnet datasets in particular.

Comment: You can find some good sources at http://roberto.perdisci.com/useful-links

Comment: You can find the updated and labelled datasets containing botnet traffic on the following link http://mcfp.weebly.com/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One malware that I know is available and used for building botnets is [kaiten.c](http://pastebin.com/K64iWPUW)

Answer (score 2):

On the following links, you can find some bot samples that were created for learning and research purposes:
http://code.google.com/p/viperbot/

http://code.google.com/p/turbot/

Answer (score -1):

CTU-13 DataSet, available at http://mcfp.weebly.com/the-ctu-13-dataset-a-labeled-dataset-with-botnet-normal-and-background-traffic.html.